# Android .properties file with variable holding different values based on the current build variant

Tags: android, android-studio, properties-file

I have a `.property` file which at the moment is like this:
`com.myapp.token = myGenericString`

What I would like to have is to have different values for different build variants. Something like:

```
if (BuildConfig == Release) {
    com.myapp.token = myReleaseString
} else {
    com.myapp.token = myOtherString
}
```

I'm new to Android so I'm not even sure it's possible.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.properties` do not support that, but you can do this with [string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource), for example:

`app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` and `app/src/debug/res/values/strings.xml`

one does not even have to differ in code then, the resource location is internally being changed.

Comment: It looks like I only have one `strings.xml` file at the moment located in `app/src/main/res/values/`

Comment: @carlodonz when you create a `debug` directory beside the `main` directory (alias "source set"), these files will be overloaded in debug mode. this also works for other resources and classes, which shall only be available in debug mode. for the `Manifest.xml` this works, too.

Comment: the problem is that I'm using an external framework and in the installation guide they say to use the `.properties` file for it. But I would like to have different values for it based on release or anything else

Comment: @carlodonz I've already explained this in my answer...and while you don't mind to tell which framework it is, I can only tell that this approach will lead nowhere - while your example can be done with debug resources, without having to tell the framework which version of the file to use.

Comment: sure I can tell you, it's NewRelic for Android, specifically step 5.
"ProGuard only: Create a `newrelic.properties` file. In your project’s root directory (projectname/app), add a `newrelic.properties` file containing this setting:
`com.newrelic.application_token=your_token`

Comment: @carlodonz since the pre-defined location, where the file is being expected (no matter what, unless one could change that), is `app/newrelic.properties` - you could only build with two package names, using `applicationIdSuffix '.debug'` for `buildType` `debug` - and possibly also add these two package-names on the New Relic console. this at least works for me with Crashlytics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180296/discussion-between-carlodonz-and-martin-zeitler).